# Can the map file of a Windows executable be made writable?

Tags: c++, windows, file, memory

When a Windows EXE is loaded it is mapped into memory. This map locks the file and prevents any normal modifications to, or replacements of, the file. However, since it is mapped as Copy-on-Write, could you change it to Write and then modify memory to change the contents of the file?

Comment: This "feature" would only be appealing to malware authors.  COW in this context is a Unix feature, the fork() approach.  Windows follows the VMS spawn() approach, explicitly to avoid this hack.

Comment: Pretty judgemental of you. How do you do small binary patches of deployed software, batch files? Specialized patch software? There are a lot of reasons being able to modify a running executable would be useful that have nothing to do with malware. Besides, this is not a "why" question, this is a "how" question.

Comment: If you are trying to allocated memory that can eventually be executed, you should look into [`VirtualAlloc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`VirtualProtect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That said, the use-case for this is very obscure, do you mind providing some details?

Comment: Can I please get an answer to my question instead of interrogations concerning my motives by self-appointed police officers.

Comment: You can't, there is no "how".  An executable file cannot be patched when it is loaded in a process.  Big reason for Windows Update always making your machine reboot.

Comment: @TylerDurden: when someone asks a question that sounds rather strange it's common that we are dealing with an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - that's why in such cases often you'll get inquires about the "bigger picture".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Changing the protection to Write and updating the memory merely updates your process's private copy of the file's bytes. (You have effectively created process-local memory that is conveniently initialized to the file's current contents.) The actual file remains unchanged.

Comment: Not exactly the answer I was hoping for, but I guess thats the answer.